# Concatenate elements of an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have a list of hrefs with product data:name and it's id. First of all i removed prod Id that i'll use as separate variable.
After this, the remained part of href should be used as the product name.

```
var prodHref = document.querySelectorAll('.widget-products-list-item-label');
  var allHref = [];
   for(var i=0;i<prodHref.length;i++){
  allHref.push(prodHref[i].href.split('/')[5])
  }
  var prodName = [];
   for(var i=0;i<allHref .length;i++){
  prodName.push(allHref [i].slice(0, -1))
  }
  
  var prodNameNew=[];
  for(var i=0;i<prodName .length;i++){
  prodNameNew.push(prodName[i].slice(0, -1))
  }
```

So, the final result is on the attached screen. N

How i have concatenate all the elements of each array in order to get new arrays in the following format: Nokia G20 4 64 Albastru, Motorola G60 gri etc
Thank You

[image]

Comment: please post the input data, your code, and the expected output ... a picture of input data is useless, your code is absent, and a vague description of the expected output is less than useless

Comment: Assuming you're after string elements, you can use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) as you push

Comment: assuming you have a 2d array and want a 1d array ... array has a `flat` method ... easy - or you can `newStr1.push(...newStr[i])` in your picture of code

Comment: @Olga I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to capitalize the items of the inner arrays and then join them by space.

One way to do it is:

```
let result = arr.map(a => a.map(capitalize))
  .map(a => a.join(" "))
```

where `capitalize` should be a function that takes a string and returns a string with first letter in upper case if possible.
You can find this in answers for the more specific SO question:
[How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Comment: `const capitalize = str => str.replace(/\w/, x => x.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 3 separate loops, we can get the substring based on single iteration only using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [String.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

```js
const prodHref = [{
  href: "https://abc/def/ghi/alpha/mno"
}, {
  href: "https://abc1/def1/ghi1/beta/mno1"
}, {
  href: "https://abc2/def2/ghi2/gamma/mno2"
}, {
  href: "https://abc3/def3/ghi3/omicron/mno3"
}];

const allHref = prodHref.map((obj) => obj.href.split('/')[5].slice(0, -2));

console.log(allHref);
```

Now you can use [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to join the result array.

```js
const allHref = ["alp", "be", "gam", "omicr"];

console.log(allHref.join(" "));
```